# Using the Java Sound API in a web-app deployed on heroku

Tags: java, heroku, web-applications, midi, javasound

We are working on a project for creating music based on crowd sourcing. People vote for every note until the vote is closed, and then move on to the next vote until the canvas for the music is filled. A similar project is crowdsound, if you want to get an idea of what it looks like.

We've hosted the .war on heroku and we've managed to make everything work, except the sound. Every time we try to call the Java Sound API (we use the midi synthesizer), we get the following error:

```
2017-03-10T09:49:01.338821+00:00 app[web.1]: javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException: Can not open line
2017-03-10T09:49:01.339228+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer.open(SoftSynthesizer.java:1155)
2017-03-10T09:49:01.339288+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer.open(SoftSynthesizer.java:1066)
2017-03-10T09:49:01.339340+00:00 app[web.1]:    at music.MusicPlayer.run(MusicPlayer.java:99)
2017-03-10T09:49:01.339391+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-03-10T09:49:01.340759+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.
2017-03-10T09:49:01.340869+00:00 app[web.1]:    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(AudioSystem.java:479)
2017-03-10T09:49:01.340924+00:00 app[web.1]:    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(AudioSystem.java:606)
2017-03-10T09:49:01.340975+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer.open(SoftSynthesizer.java:1095)
2017-03-10T09:49:01.341045+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 3 more
```

Does this mean that we cannot use the midi synthesizer in a web app, or is there some way to make this work?

Comment: Is that code executed on the cloud server or on the client? Do you see any source data lines when you enumerate them?

Comment: @CL. I am not exactly sure, but playing the sound should be client sided. The application runs in a tomcat server that is run on their cloud servers (perhaps in a VM). As for the second part of your quesiton, I've never dealt with source data lines, so could you tell me how to do that? If it helps, running it on a local server gives no errors with sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply cannot play a sound from a Java WAR, because it's executed on the server side. Additionally, the heroku instance may be lacking the sound hardware altogether.

If you'd like to generate sound that is then served to the web client, you need to either use some MIDI renderer that produces a sound file, and then serve the resulting audio file to the client (e.g. as WAV file) or simply serve MIDI to the client and have the browser play the MIDI via a library like e.g. [MIDI.js](http://www.midijs.net).